# Strange work of angular component

Tags: angular, components, counter

I have not deep knowledge in angular2. In simple example I'm trying to create an component. Code is below:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'counter',
  templateUrl: './counter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./counter.component.css'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CounterComponent {
  @Input()
  count: number;

  @Output()
  change: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();

  increment() {
    this.count++;
    this.change.emit(this.count);
  }

  decrement() {
    if(this.count > 0)
    {
    this.count--;
    this.change.emit(this.count);
    }
  }

  reset()
  {
    this.count = 0;
    this.change.emit(this.count);
  }


  constructor()
  {

  }
}
```

template code:

```
<span>{{count}}</span>
<div>
  <button (click)="increment()">Increment</button>
  <button (click)="decrement()">Decrement</button>
  <button (click)="reset()">Reset</button>
</div>
```

I trying using this component:

```
<counter [count]="5" (change)="countChange($event)"></counter>
<counter [count]="10" (change)="countChange($event)"></counter>
```

and in "ts"

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';
  countChange(event) {

  }
}
```

When I watching result in browser i see that count field for first component is NaN but for second it is correctly and equaly an 10. Also increment, dicrement and reset events working correctly only for the second component. Why and what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Seems it works for me. https://plnkr.co/edit/vEEcv1oA7CWJU5txotu9?p=preview

Comment: Thank you but I'm using another structure of folders and files. It's looks following https://plnkr.co/edit/e3cBRF2WwIGfbmLXjHLS